# Determine Registered Admin Menus

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, dashboard, add-menu-page

Is it possible to obtain a list of which Top Level Admin Menus have been registered via some plugin?

I'm talking about menus registered with: [`add_menu_page();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global variable `$menu` to see which top level menus are registered.

```
function determine_menus() {
    global $menu;
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($menu); exit; // uncomment to see the array of menus in back-end
}
add_action('admin_init', 'determine_menus');
```